# Page break after chapter in appendix using landscape

Tags: appendices, landscape, blank-page

I get a random blank page after using `pdflscape` with an image in my appendices

I have already tried implementing `afterpage` to no avail. 
I still get a blank landscape page when using the above code.

Minimum example:

```
\documentclass[twoside,openright,11pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\title{test}
\author{Mr Bloggs}
\date{March 2016}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
blah blah blah



 % Appendices
\makeatletter\@openrightfalse\makeatother % Fix for random blank page after appendices
\begin{appendices}
    \chapter{Test Results} \label{appendix:tests}

    \begin{landscape}
        \includegraphics[width=1.3\textwidth]{test-results.png}
    \end{landscape}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

Comment: please add a minimal working example, and what is the question?

Comment: @touhami added example

Comment: I can't see any problem in your code: 1) if you mean blank page before `appendix A` it's just the standard of openright and you have already the correct fix 2) if you mean the vertical  space after `Appendix A` and before the image, this is because of landscape (landscape start  a newpage)

Comment: Its a blank page after the appendix chapter heading but before the picture, the blank page is also landscape

Comment: OK. I don't have this problem but I can think that your image is to large so you need to change `\includegraphics[width=1.3\textwidth]{test-results.png}`  try some thing less than `1.3\textwidth`